# Deleting rows where two column values appeared before

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
user    institution      group       result      quiz
a       Company          1a          True        zzz
a       Company          1a          False       yyy
a       Company          1a          True        yyy
a       Company          1a          False       www
b       Company          1a          False       www
c       Company          1b          False       yyy
c       Company          1b          True        yyy
d       Company          1c          True        qqq
d       Company          1c          True        zzz
d       Company          1c          True        yyy
e       Company          1c          False       zzz
e       Company          1c          False       yyy
e       Company          1c          False       yyy
```

The institution is the same (in the original dataset I have multiple institutions, but I split the dataset into multiple dataframes like the one above). The users can answer multiple quizzes multiple times. Each user can only be in one group.

**How could I only take into consideration the first answer of each user to every quiz he answers?**

```
    user    institution      group       FirstResult      quiz
    a       Company          1a          True             zzz
    a       Company          1a          False            yyy
    a       Company          1a          False            www
    b       Company          1a          False            www
    c       Company          1b          False            yyy
    d       Company          1c          True             qqq
    d       Company          1c          True             zzz
    d       Company          1c          True             yyy
    e       Company          1c          False            zzz
    e       Company          1c          False            yyy
```

I tried to naively and manually delete the rows using `df.drop`, but this impossible when the dataframe is big. The condition would be basically that `user` and `quiz` occur a second, third, nth time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has the [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) function:

```
deduped = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["user", "institution", "group", "quiz"], keep="first")
```